# How to transform list of variable length from one python dataframe column into rows?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am trying to transform lists from one dataframe column into rows but not sure how to efficiently do that in python?
My actual data has thousands of rows and lists of variable lengths (in column `Specs` but to simplify, I will use the example below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'Type': 'A', 'Specs': [['a1', 50], ['a2', 14]]},
   {'Type': 'B', 'Specs': [['b1', 20], ['b2', 25], ['b3', 15], ['b4', 10]]},
   {'Type': 'C', 'Specs': [['c1', 32]]} ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The final result should be equivalent to the output from the dataframe below

```
data_out= [{'Type': 'A', 'model':'a1', 'qty': 50},
   {'Type': 'A', 'model':'a2', 'qty': 14},
   {'Type': 'B', 'model':'b1', 'qty': 20},
   {'Type': 'B', 'model':'b2', 'qty': 25},
   {'Type': 'B', 'model':'b3', 'qty': 15},
   {'Type': 'B', 'model':'b4', 'qty': 10},
   {'Type': 'C', 'model':'c1', 'qty': 32}]
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data_out)
```

I have tried to use `apply` with a function to convert each row list/value to a dataframe and getting confused how to return a dataframe for each row and expand the new dataframe with the new rows. Please let me know if I am on the wrong track and what would be the most efficient way to get the required dataframe output on large data? Thanks

```
def convert_list(my_list):
   my_df = pd.DataFrame(pv_list, columns=['model', 'qty'])
return my_df

df[['model', 'qty']] = df['Specs'].apply(convert_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `explode()`+`join()`+`DataFrame()`+`pop()`:

```
df=df.explode('Specs',ignore_index=True)
df[['Model','Qty']]=pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Specs').tolist())
#OR
#df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Specs').tolist(),columns=['Model','Qty']))
```

OR

`explode()`+`drop()`+`.str` accessor:

```
df=df.explode('Specs',ignore_index=True)
df['Model']=df['Specs'].str[0]
df['Qty']=df['Specs'].str[1]
df=df.drop('Specs',1)
```

OR

`explode()`+`pop()`+`agg()`:

```
df=df.explode('Specs',ignore_index=True)
df[['Model','Qty']]=df.pop('Specs').agg(pd.Series)
```

output of `df`:

```
   Type     Model   Qty
0   A       a1      50
1   A       a2      14
2   B       b1      20
3   B       b2      25
4   B       b3      15
5   B       b4      10
6   C       c1      32
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write any custom function or joins/merge, use `explode`

DOCS: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'Type': 'A', 'Specs': [['a1', 50], ['a2', 14]]},
   {'Type': 'B', 'Specs': [['b1', 20], ['b2', 25], ['b3', 15], ['b4', 10]]},
   {'Type': 'C', 'Specs': [['c1', 32]]} ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
# Code Example
df=df.explode('Specs').reset_index(drop=True)
df[['model','qty']] =  pd.DataFrame(df["Specs"].to_list())
df.drop('Specs', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

```
|    | Type   | model   |   qty |
|---:|:-------|:--------|------:|
|  0 | A      | a1      |    50 |
|  1 | A      | a2      |    14 |
|  2 | B      | b1      |    20 |
|  3 | B      | b2      |    25 |
|  4 | B      | b3      |    15 |
|  5 | B      | b4      |    10 |
|  6 | C      | c1      |    32 |
```

**PS:**
that's it, if it is still slow, *I would advise looking at something that is parallelised!*

Comment: Your code example was fast enough, so I won't need to look into the parallel process at least for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case try

```
s = df.pop('Specs').explode()
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),columns=['Model','Qty'],index=s.index).join(df)
Out[84]: 
  Model  Qty Type
0    a1   50    A
0    a2   14    A
1    b1   20    B
1    b2   25    B
1    b3   15    B
1    b4   10    B
2    c1   32    C
```